# Is an improvised weapon treated as similar enough to a weapon to use its properties still considered "improvised"?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, two-weapon-fighting, improvised-weaponry

In PHB, the 2nd paragraph of the description of [Improvised Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/equipment#ImprovisedWeapons) (p. 147) states:

> In many cases, an improvised weapon is similar to an actual weapon and
>   can be treated as such. For example, a table leg is akin to a club. At
>   the DM’s option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a
>   similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her
>   proficiency bonus.

If I am understanding this correctly, then the mentioned table leg (or similar object) can be treated as a [club](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/club). If that is correct, then it would have the *light* property, as the club has it. If that is also correct, that would mean I can wield a light weapon in one hand and an improvised club-like weapon in other hand, and use [*Two-Weapon Fighting*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting) with those, as both are light.

If all of that is still correct, then **can an improvised weapon that is similar enough to a real weapon - e.g. a table leg used as a club - still be treated as an improvised weapon** for the purpose of the last bullet point in the [Tavern Brawler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/tavern-brawler) feat (PHB, p. 170)?

Specific scenario that I am wondering about: I wield a [Scimitar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/scimitar) (a light weapon) in one hand and a table leg (treated as a club, so also light) in the other hand. On my turn, I attack with the table leg as my Attack action. Then one of two things happen:

1. I miss - then, as both wielded weapons are light, I proceed to attack with my scimitar (per Two-Weapon Fighting)
2. I hit - then I drop one of my weapons to free one of my hands and attempt to grapple the target.

Of course this is assuming that I have the Tavern Brawler feat, which states:

> - You are proficient with improvised weapons.
> - Your unarmed strike uses a d4 for damage.
> - When you hit a creature with an unarmed strike or an improvised weapon on your turn, you can use a bonus action to attempt to grapple the target.

Does all of that work as I've described, or is there somewhere a flaw in my reasoning?

Answer (score 12):

### Yes, it is still improvised

You are correct that an improvised weapon is still an improvised weapon, thus you still have the option to grapple the target with your **bonus action.**

> At the DM’s option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object **as if** it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

It is *still* an improvised weapon, but can be *treated* as a similar weapon (a club), if your character is proficient with it. So it has both the properties of an improvised and the similar weapon.

**Note:** This treatment also has two conditions attached: at DM's discretion, and only if the they are proficient with said weapon. Most (if not all) characters are proficient with simple weapons, however.

In short:

1. If you miss with the table leg, then you can use your bonus action only to attack with the scimitar.
2. If you hit with the leg table, then you can use your bonus action to either attack with scimitar, **or** grapple the target.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also assumed it would work that way, however I had this talk already with someone that claimed that if I treat improvised weapon as similar regular weapon it no longer act as improvised one - it was his interpretation and in I can also see the point there. Can it be somehow dissproven?

Comment: @rav the key part is "as if" which I bolded in the answer. It is *still* an improvised weapon, however at the DM's discretion, it can be treated as a similar weapon. And only to a character that is proficient with the similar weapon. I'll update for clarity.

Comment: The part of description *“At the DM’s option, a character proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus”* only reffers to DM allowing using  proficiency bonus from some other weapon which is irrelevant in case of Tavern Brawler that gives character proficiency in improvised weapons. Am I right?

Comment: @rav No. The ability to use proficiency bonus is *in addition* to be able to treat the weapon as if it were one.

Comment: @Vylix -- *Tavern Brawler* allows proficiency with improvised weapons. Thus, proficiency with a club is unnecessary.

Comment: @ravery proficiency with a weapon is needed to treat the improvised weapon as the weapon. I think all characters have proficiency with simple weapons, but if the improvised weapon is similar to a longsword, for example, you'd need proficiency with longsword to treat it as a longsword, else it can only be an improvised weapon.

Comment: @Vylix - The passage quoted applies to someone that does not have *Tavern  Brawler*. ie. At the discretion of the DM, a fighter may add proficiency when using a table leg as a club, because he is proficient with clubs. However in this case, the fighter already has proficiency because *Tavern Brawler* gives proficiency with improvised weapons (table leg), so proficiency with a club is irrelevant.

Comment: @ravery for the sake of adding proficiency bonus to attack rolls, I agree that "and use his or her proficiency bonus" seems redundant (unless there is some sort of expertise in weapon, which I think currently doesn't exist)